# Why does partialType not make properties nullable?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Does anyone know why `partialType` does not make properties nullable? It adds `@IsOptional` to properties which also allow `null` as a valid value, however the type returned from `partialType` only returns `T | undefined` instead of `T | undefined | null`, which causes a problem in TypeScript's strict null check mode. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/1916) about it; the contributor said it's an expected behavior, but I don't see how.

Comment: That's what "optional" refers to in TypeScript, `T | undefined` (see e.g. the built-in [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility type). That's consistent with the runtime behaviour - if you don't explicitly set a property or pass a parameter, the default value is `undefined` (_not_ `null`). `| null` would usually be described as "nullable"; if `null` is valid that should be part of the type _before_ making it optional.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The official definition of `@IsOptional` is that `It checks if given value is empty (=== null, === undefined) and if so, ignores all the validators on the property.`  which clearly means it can be ` | null ` both theoretically and in action however `partialType` ignores the ` | null` fact even though it applies `@IsOptional` decorator to all properties. How is it expected that `T | defined` may end up being ` === null`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be fixed by wrapping `partialType` with `NullableType`

```
type Nullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] | null;
};

export function NullableType<T>(classRef: Type<T>): Type<Nullable<T>> {
  return classRef as Type<Nullable<T>>;
}
```

Comment: Nice. You can also include the partial and make it recursive if you want the nullable partiality to apply all the way down a deep nested structure, like `type DeepNullable<T> = Partial<{[P in keyof T]: DeepNullable<T[P]> | null;}>`